# Percentage in a Pivot Table (same dimension on row and column

Tags: mdx

As an example, in reality there are hundreds of distinct values:

```
      A=200 B=100 C=25

     so A/A = 100%, A/B = 200%, A/C = 800% etc.,
```

I need to get something similar to the following table using MDX, the column is denominator and the row is numerator:

```
      A    B    C 
A   100%  50%  12.5%


B   200% 100%  25%


C   800% 400%  100%
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you change the cube, or do you need this for an existing cube that cannot be changed?

Comment: it'd have to be the same cube.

Comment: My question was meant to ask: Are you able to change the design of the cube, or has it to stay as it is?

Comment: You can make a calculated member, but we would need to understand what these values are and what the structure of your cube is like to give you a good answer.  Does A/B/C represent a category that is a dimension attribute and the numbers are all the same measure?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you want to have a hierarchy on two axes. This is not possible in MDX. What you could do is to add the dimension containing it a second time to the cube, giving it another name, similarly to using a "role playing dimension", but not defining any relationship. This means that looking at the cube, tab "Dimension usage", the whole row of the new dimension would be empty (gray). Then the user can drag one hierarchy to the rows, and the other to the columns.

As you did not state names, I just assume the following for my answer:

- The hierarchy you have so far is named `[Orig].[Hier]`,
- the hierarchy you added is named `[Copy].[Hier]`,
- the measure you have so far (the 200, 100, 25) is called `Value`, and
- the measure you need (the 100%, 200%, ...) is called `Ratio`.

Then define the measure `Ratio` as follows:

```
([Orig].[Hier].CurrentMember, [Measures].[Value]) 
/
(LinkMember([Copy].[Hier].CurrentMember, [Orig].[Hier]),  [Measures].[Value])
,FORMAT_STRING='#.#%'
```